# radio button's disabled property is not working inside the reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

Radio button's disabled property is not working inside the reactive form but it's working fine when I put radio button outside the reactive form.

I have a condition like if my current status is **CLOSED** I should allow the user to edit radio button inside the reactive form I already tried with Disabled property of radio button but no luck

**component.ts**

```
conducttestlm:any={
    isReadOnly:false
}
this.condutTestLM=this.formBuilder.group({
    "testStatus":['',Validators.required],
})
if(success.data.status=='CLOSED'){
    this.conducttestlm.isReadOnly=true;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="condutTestLM">
    <div class="row radio-top">
        <div class="col-md-6 p-l-15">
            <label class="radio-box">
                <input formControlName="testStatus" name="testStatus" [(ngModel)]="conducttestlm.teststatus" [disabled]="conducttestlm.isReadOnly" value="Pass" type="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                <span class="font-style">Pass</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 p-l-15">
            <label class="radio-box">
                <input formControlName="testStatus" name="testStatus" [(ngModel)]="conducttestlm.teststatus"  [disabled]="conducttestlm.isReadOnly" value="Fail" type="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                <span class="font-style">Fail</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form >
```

I need to disable the radio button

Comment: Plz use ng-run.com to post an example.

Comment: Don't use template driven approach along with reactive forms. If you are using reactive forms then don't use `ngModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use template driven approach while using reactive forms. Have your code like:

```
<form [formGroup]="condutTestLM">
  <div class="row radio-top">
      <div class="col-md-6 p-l-15">
        <label class="radio-box">
          <input formControlName="testStatus" name="testStatus" [attr.disabled]="conducttestlm.isReadOnly ? true : null" value="Pass" type="radio">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
          <span class="font-style">Pass</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 p-l-15">
        <label class="radio-box">
          <input formControlName="testStatus" name="testStatus" [attr.disabled]="conducttestlm.isReadOnly ? true: null" value="Fail" type="radio">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
          <span class="font-style">Fail</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncxac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You will notice that I have used `attr.disabled` instead of `disabled` to disable individual radio buttons.
To know the difference between `attr.disabled` and `disabled`, you can have a look at [this link](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-attribute-binding-example). In a gist, `attr.disabled` is an HTML attribute while `disabled` is a DOM property. There are some HTML attributes for which DOM properties don't exist, as shown in the added link.

From [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property)

> > Attributes are defined by HTML. Properties are defined by the DOM (Document Object Model).
>
> - A few HTML attributes have 1:1 mapping to properties. id is one    example.
> - Some HTML attributes don't have corresponding properties. colspan is    one example.
> - Some DOM properties don't have corresponding attributes. textContent    is one example.
> - Many HTML attributes appear to map to properties ... but not in the    way you might think!

This is not true for input boxes and `disabled` DOM property. There indeed is a `disabled` DOM property but there is some issue while using it individually over radio buttons. See this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11763). The solution I provided is more of a workaround to achieve individual disabling of radio buttons.

Comment: its working fine but why i need to use [attr.disabled] why not [disabled].I Could not find any docs about [attr.disabled] .Could You Explain it

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the status change is not being detected while rendering. First of all:

```
// instead of using this: 
[disabled]="conducttestlm.isReadOnly"

// Use the readonly attribute:
[readonly]="conducttestlm.isReadOnly"
```

Next, use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to detect any changes manually:

```
// import it: 
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// and inject it into your contructor:
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    ...
}

// call it
if(success.data.status=='CLOSED'){
    this.conducttestlm.isReadOnly=true;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Should detect changes in status immedietly on run. If not, try console logging your `conducttestlm.isReadOnly` value to ensure it's changing.

If you want to use template driven attribute, you can use `[attr.disabled]` instead `[disabled]` as well.